# Short way to extract sublist from list in python by given conditions

Tags: python, arrays, list, class

I have particular problem which I have to make the most simple yet still reflecting issue, and need to know is there a short way to do it.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.bar=c

objects = [Foo(x) for x in 'ab..$...$x.z']
```

Now we have list of objects and here is the problem; I have to shorten list to all objects with `'.'` between two with `'$'` *bar* attributes from left and right of given index. 
Index is returned by some calculation and should not necessarily hits object with `bar='.'` so in that case `[]` is returned.

So the `[x.bar for x in objects]` should be `['.','.','.']`. I tried to represent the problem by the most simple way, sorry for any inconvenience...

The point is, code should be short. Thank you.

Comment: How many '$' characters can there be in the string?

Comment: Two or more, but it doesn't matter because the index should not hit the dot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.bar=c

objects = [Foo(x) for x in 'ab..$111$x.z$222']
```

Get the indices of the sentinals

```
z = [i for i, thing in enumerate(objects) if thing.bar == '$']
```

Extract the objects between the sentinals using those indices.

```
for i,j in zip(z, z[1:]):
    print map(operator.attrgetter('bar'), objects[i+1:j])

>>> 
['1', '1', '1']
['x', '.', 'z']
>>>
```

To create the list of objects - one sub-list for each interval between the sentinals:

```
what_i_want = [objects[i+1:j] for i,j in zip(z, z[1:])]
```

Comment: Although I upvoted all the answers here, this is the one which hits the problem in concise way. Thx.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted separate sub-lists.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re` to do that:

In case you have 1 substring:

```
objects = [x for x in re.search('\$(.*?)\$', 'ab..$...$x.z').groups()[0]]
```

In case you have unknown number of substrings:

```
objects = [y for x in re.finditer('\$(.*?)\$', 'ab..$123$x.,,,$abc$,,,') for y in x.groups()[0]]
```

Comment: Upvote for the second case, but that's list of objects not the strings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a dictionary for get a collection of objects and use regex for get every thing between tow `$`:

```
>>> objects = {'a%d'%i:Foo(x) for i,x in enumerate(list(re.search(r'\$(.*)\$','ab..$...$x.z').group(1)))}
>>> objects
{'a1': <__main__.Foo object at 0x7ff1a6952b90>, 'a0': <__main__.Foo object at 0x7ff1a6952a50>, 'a2': <__main__.Foo object at 0x7ff1a6952bd0>}
>>> objects['a0'].bar
'.'
>>> objects['a1'].bar
'.'
>>> objects['a2'].bar
'.'
```

then you can get the object list with `objects.values()` .

```
>>> obj=objects.values()
>>> [x.bar for x in obj]
['.', '.', '.']
```

and if you dont want to use dictionary and want the list of objects use a list comprehension like following :

```
>>> objects = [Foo(x) for x in list(re.search(r'\$(.*)\$','ab..$...$x.z').group(1))]
>>> [x.bar for x in objects]
['.', '.', '.']
```

Comment: While upvoted, it still doesn't represents the object list as the otput.

Comment: @Alex you can use get the values with `objects.values()`

Comment: I gave 'ab..$...$x.z' just an example as well as class example but the objects are already made. Thank you for your effort, and sorry if I misunderstood (i.e. you're making an objects with different syntax where desired objects are filtered before construction).

Comment: if you dont want use dictionary you can just use a list ! that i'll add to answer !

Comment: I admire your devotion to dictionaries, but I clearly stated that the objects are **already** constructed, and they're should be extracted from the list of class instances. Thank you anyway...upvoting ur comments.

Comment: @Alex thanks , did you mean that you have a list of objects of all the character of `'ab..$...$x.z'` and you want to extract the objects related to `...` ?

Comment: `'ab..$...$x.z'` string is here just to build example of objects list with one character each and yes, I want to extract objects related to `...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
objects = [Foo(x) for x in 'ab..$...$x.z'.split('$')[1]]
```

Output of `[x.bar for x in objects]` is `['.','.','.']`

This is sure to work, for the given input (i.e only two '$' symbol)

Comment: Sorry, now edited the question and added a case when index should not point the desired objects ( with dot ).